# Need to include @Json non-null in swagger code gen

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I need to add @Json non-null in call level but I am not able to do it from swagger code gen.

Hence, could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean that you're generating Java code from an OpenAPI definition, and you want the generated classes to have the `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation?

Comment: Thanks Helen. yes correct, i want to include this annotation in generated class.

Comment: Do these Q&As answer your question? [How can I produce @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) for particular generated POJO from Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71158760/113116), [Adding Jackson annotation to a Swagger generated class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55517796/113116), [How to customize Swagger Codegen to generate models that ignore null values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42997380/113116), [Swagger Codegen ignore null fields for POJO classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45031264/113116)

Answer (score -2):

you can use the @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema annotation on your method parameters. This annotation allows you to specify the data type, format, and other properties of the parameter, and you can use it to specify that the parameter is required (non-null) using the required property.

Here is how you might use the @Schema annotation to specify that a method parameter is required:

```
@GET
@Path("/users/{id}")
public User getUser(
  @PathParam("id") @Schema(required = true) String userId
) {
  ...
}
```

In this example, the @Schema annotation is used on the userId parameter to specify that it is required. This will ensure that the generated code includes the @Json non-null annotation on the parameter, which will enforce the requirement at runtime.

You can also use the @Schema annotation to specify other properties of the parameter, such as its data type, format, and description. For more information, you can refer to the Swagger Code Gen documentation.

Comment: The OP is not writing Java code manually, they are generating the code using Swagger Codegen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).